# EF migrations ignore data changes

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have an initial DB migration. Now I need to create the first incremental migration. When I create the first incremental migration with

```
add-migration Incremental1
```

it contains not only the table changes but all data changes as well. For example for rows that were added in between into the table it contains `DeleteData` commands:

```
migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
            table: "SystemResources",
            keyColumn: "Id",
            keyValue: 1);
```

Is there some setting for generating only table changes (added/removed columns) and ignoring all data changes (inserted data rows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to:

1. disable seeding of data by commenting out all `modelBuilder.Entity<T>().HasData` statements,
2. create the incremental migration with `add-migration`,
3. manually remove all `DeleteData` / `InsertData` commands from the incremental migration,
4. run `update-database`.

After this, the seed data is no longer part of the model snapshopt (`<Database>ModelSnapshot.cs` file) and is therefore no longer tracked by migrations.

This also means the next incremental migration will not contain any `DeleteData` / `InsertData` statements.